# How do I re-open an issue in GitHub if it's closed by a stale bot?

Tags: github, github-issues

I opened the issue, but because there was no answer for a long time the stale bot has flagged it 'staled' then finally that bot closed it.
As the owner of the issue, how do I re-open it?

By the way, I know that GitHub has these rules:

- you can open issues
- you can comment on all existing issues (open or closed)
- you can close your own issues
- you can re-open your own issues if you closed them yourself
- you cannot close or re-open issues opened by someone else
- you cannot re-open your own issues if a repo collaborator closed them

But my case is none of the above since I'm the owner of the issue and the issue wasn't closed by repo collaborator but by a bot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though repo owner/collaborator did not close it, it is still treated as like that. So only repo owner or collaborator can reopen it as far as I know. Bots will be given collaborator level of permission to carry out all these kind of tasks on repositories.